# Deploying a SOAP Webservice implementation from the module directory in JBoss Wildfly

Tags: java, soap, jboss, web.xml, wildfly

I've been experiencing issues deploying a SOAP webservice implementation which class files live inside of a Wildfly Module.  The module is a global module which the Web Application has access to (I know b/c it is able to access other classes stored within the module) and no deployment errors occur.  However, I also never receive a log stating "Adding service endpoint metadata" as it would under normal circumstances and a wsdl is never generated.

For reference, I have 3 other SOAP webservices deployed in the same container but all of their implementation classes exist inside of a jar residing within their corresponding web application.  Is their a known issue with storing the webservice implementation within a Module?  For reasons I cannot disclose, this needs to not be an issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using annotations for the web service implementation within the module?

Comment: Yes, I'm using annotation WebService and WebMethod with the targetnamespace and service name predefined.  Literally if I take WebServiceA and put it inside a jar within the lib directory of WebAppB, everything works fine.  However, if I move WebServiceA's jar to a jboss module, it doesn't deploy.  No error is shown and but I can guarantee the module is loaded properly as I can access other classes within the jar.

Comment: Ok, try adding in `MANIFEST.MF` something like `Dependencies: org.foo annotations` where `org.foo` is your module. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/JBoss+Modules#JBossModules-Annotationscanning

Comment: Thanks but as I said the module is already configured properly including the added reference to the MANIFEST.  If it wasn't, I wouldn't be able to access the other classes referenced within the jar and runtime errors would be thrown.

Comment: Including `annotations`? See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/JBoss+Modules#JBossModules-Annotationscanning

Comment: Ahhhh!  I've never seen the annotations piece before.  I see that when trying to do that I get an error thrown by the module loading that no META-INF/jandex.idx was found.  I'm having a difficult time determing where and how to generate it.  Does this go inside every jar in the module, the single jar that contains annotations or does it go inside the application??

Comment: Okay so it appears i needed it in only the single jar.  Now I'm getting an error the webservice implementation... "has the wrong component type, it cannot be used as a web component."  Thoughts?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I got it, after adding the annotations reference to the Dependencies I simply had to use the jandex maven plugin when building my jar and it fixed everything.  The reason I had the issue was because I accidentally had a @stateless annotation in my webservice which caused it to throw an error.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conversing with @federico-sierra we found the issue to be with the dependency declaration in /META-INF/MANFIEST.MF of the web application.

My original manifest file appeared as such:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.webservice.impl.library, org.apache.log4j
Built-By: usera
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.2
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archive
```

When the dependency line should have contained 'annotations' next to my webservice classpath:

```
Dependencies: org.webservice.impl.library annotations, org.apache.log4j
```

Furthermore, after making this change my webservice implementation jar needed to be recompiled with the maven jandex plugin so the required jandex.idx would get generated inside of the jar.  The maven plugin description is location at: https://github.com/wildfly/jandex-maven-plugin.  Note: There is an ANT plugin available if needed.